# PHP/MySQL Login -> Schema for each customer

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, schema

Hi fellow programmers,

I'm trying to create a login system for my web application that contains multiple customers at same time.

Each customer has their own schema in the MySQL database.

My problem is that I don't know how to change the schema on a succesful login so it matches the customer schema in the database.

The flows works as following:

1. login.html: Provide login details
2. Take connection to database and the schema "info" that holds all
   the login details from all customers.
3. Login.php: I check if the username and pass fits if yes I want to redirect 
   to welcome.html (everything works, problem occur in step 4)
4. The customer should now be able to see their data on the frontend since it's
   now connected to Schema "customer_name" and not "info" anymore.

I posted some pictures that might help understand my coding.

Picture 1: [login.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0YRS.png)

Picture 2: [dbconnection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWunC.png)

Picture 3: [login.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeQos.png)

Picture 4: [Schema's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snphE.png)

Thank you very much!! Every help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **mysqli_select_db** to change the current selected database.

```
<?php
//connect to the database
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');

// make foo the current db
mysqli_select_db($link,'foo');
?>
```

But the question is, wouldn't it be better to store the customer information in one database. Why would you have to switch databases everytime someone logs into your system?

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion!
Regarding to your question:
You might be right, it's better to have just 1 database. I'm new to databases overall and I'm not quite sure how to recreate the database. My thought was to seperate the customer tables in different schemas.

I tried following: 
    if (password_verify($password, $hashedPassword)) {
        mysqli_select_db($conn, $username);
        header('Location: ../../../index.html');
        exit;
    }

Comment: A different Schema for each customer does not sound good to me, because it defeats normalization. The different customers are stored in the same table because they are all customers. and have the same kind  of data.

Comment: Hmm, that's correct! I'll will look into redesigning the database. 
Thank you very much Alexeran! Each customer contains 30 tables of different data. Adding alle customer in same Schema is going to lead in alot of tables then I have to specify each table with example: customer1_table1? :)